# Best practice to propagate transitive targets from a library?

Tags: cmake

I'm currently writing a library (let's call it *mylib*) using modern cmake (i.e. with proper targets and properties). It's was all good until I encountered a 3rdparty dependency (let's call it *libfoo*) that doesn't define imported targets in its `FooConfig.cmake`.

For this, I decided to write my own custom `FindFoo.cmake` module where I define the target `Foo::Foo` of the dependency myself. This works fine for building *mylib*, but fails when attempting to link an executable against it (after installing it).

Here is a simplified version of `MyLibConfig.cmake`:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Foo 1.0 REQUIRED)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyLibTargets.cmake)
```

Now, when I try to link against *mylib* from an executable (let's call it *myexec*), I get the following error:

```
Target "myexec" links to target "Foo::Foo" but the target was
not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

I understand why this happens: the target `Foo::Foo` was defined in my custom `FindFoo.cmake` module (and it's a public dependency of *mylib*). However, this module is not available to *myexec* when it loads `MyLibConfig.cmake`.

The question now is, what's the best possible solution to this problem? One idea that I saw was to install `FindFoo.cmake` with *mylib* and add it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` when running `MyLibConfig.cmake`, bus this seems wrong to me. How can I make transitive targets available to users?

Comment: How do you expect a user of your library finds its `Foo::Foo` dependency *without* `FindFoo.cmake` shipped with your library? Note, that `MyLibConfig.cmake` is used after installing the library, and only installed files are available to it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Question is, how do you use `FindFoo.cmake`? Installing it in some directory (probably the same as `MyLibConfig.cmake`) and adding this directory to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in your `MyLibConfig.cmake` works, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: I mean, that in any case `FindFoo.cmake` **should be installed**. Because you (your project) is a provider of that file, then you should install it. As for better choice for directory where the file should be installed... I don't know. In my opinion, having this file near the `MyLibConfig.cmake` isn't bad.